# Suppose I want to check using if statement like that: IF(?p a dbo:Person,1,0)

Tags: sparql

```
SELECT * WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indian_Institute_of_Technology_Kharagpur> 

<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/director> ?p.

OPTIONAL{?p rdfs:label ?s}

BIND(IF(isURI(?p) && ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.,?s,?p) AS ?r)

}
```

Comment: `exists` function is the way to go. And next time, a  bit more text in your question would be good

Comment: BIND(IF(isURI(?p) && exists{?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.},?s,?p) AS ?r)            If i did so in above code  ,no result ,compiler error.pls help - @AKSW

Comment: Ehm what? Why do you write `,?s,?p` instead of `,1,0` as mentioned in your question title? And why the semicolon and a dot inside the `exists` part?

Comment: @AKSW ,I am using the code that is wriiten above .but as you told for  exists function,i modified the  code as         BIND(IF(isURI(?p) && exists(?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>),?s,?p) AS ?r).But this is not working . pls help me

Comment: @AjiteshMandal - Please edit your question to reflect current effort. Conversation in comments makes questions harder to answer. See the help for [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

Comment: @AjiteshMandal `SELECT * WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indian_Institute_of_Technology_Kharagpur> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/director> ?p.

OPTIONAL{?p rdfs:label ?s}

BIND(IF(isURI(?p) && xsd:boolean(exists{?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>}),?s,?p) AS ?r)

}`

Comment: @TallTed I guess, there is still the bug with the return type of the `exists` function. As you can see in my comment above, I had to case it to `xsd:boolean` in order to get it working

Answer (score 2):

There is still an [issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/693) with the `exists` function in `IF` statements with Virtuoso. As a workaround, cast the output of `exists` to `xsd:boolean`:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 dbr:Indian_Institute_of_Technology_Kharagpur dbo:director ?p. 
 OPTIONAL{?p rdfs:label ?s} 
 BIND(IF(isURI(?p) && xsd:boolean(exists{?p a dbo:Person}),?s,?p) AS ?r) 
}
```

Comment: ,I think this problem exsist till now.